# partially initialized module 'app' has no attribute 'excute_job_search' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, module-export

I am trying to populate parameters to use it on the backed with the user input, like email and name etc.., when I have imported the app.py to gui.py and export gui.py to app.py I have had this error about the circular import

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'app' has no attribute 'excute_job_search' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

the code is the following

```
from tkinter import *
import app

def get_input():
    email = e1.get()
    password = e2.get()
    number_of_jobs = e3.get()
    job_title = e4.get()
    location = e5.get()
    print(email, password, number_of_jobs, job_title, location)

b = Button(window, text="Confirm", width=10, command=get_input)
b1 = Button(window, text="Excute", width=12, command=app.excute_job_search)
```

Comment: where do you create `window`?

Comment: why do you export `GUI` to `app.py`? It is wrong idea. You should use `GUI` only in file `gui.py` and then you don't have to import it to `app.py`. What do you have in `app.py`? Or you should put all GUI in functions which gets expected values as argument - and then you don't have to import `app.py`. And then you can import it to `app.py` and run in `app`

Comment: `import *` is not preferred - see more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: in gui.py you use `e1`, `e2`, etc. which probably are not created in `gui.py` - it is also wrong idea. You should keep all GUI in `gui.py`.